# Scan message must contain angles from -x to x

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, message, scan, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I follow the tutorial [turtlebot_simulator](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_simulator/Tutorials/hydro/Make%20a%20map%20and%20navigate%20with%20it) to make a map in a simulated world.But when I run

> roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo gmapping_demo.launch

a error that scan message must contain angles from -x to x occurs, as show below. How to deal with it.

`[ERROR] [1433813576.466253926, 24.270000000]: Scan message must contain angles from -x to x, i.e. angle_min = -angle_max`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210849/scan-message-must-contain-angles-from--x-to-x/) by [Leejamin](https://answers.ros.org/users/21803/leejamin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2015-06-08

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tosandip](https://answers.ros.org/users/22300/tosandip/) on 2015-07-10**:
I am facing the same issue, any possible solution?

**Comment by [forinkzan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20935/forinkzan/) on 2015-07-14**:
me too , do you have any possible solution

**Comment by [tosandip](https://answers.ros.org/users/22300/tosandip/) on 2015-07-15**:
No i have not found any.. starting looking at jackal robot.

**Comment by [chuong](https://answers.ros.org/users/23203/chuong/) on 2015-07-15**:
I have the same problem. This is the new behaviour in the latest ros-indigo-gmapping-1.3.7 package. CHANGELOG.rst says:
....

- Added cfloat include
- Change arbitrary constant to FLT_EPSILON
- Added check that scan goes from -x to x
  .......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, thank you for sharing the data. A fix was merged upstream in 1.3.8: it just reached shadow fixed so please test. The fix centers the scan before sending them to gmapping, whether they're slightly / completely off-centered or even upside-down.

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2015-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This error is due to recent change in gmapping package.
This can be fixed by modifying and recompiling the gmapping package as follows:

```
$ wget http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-gmapping/ros-indigo-gmapping_1.3.7.orig.tar.gz
$ mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src
$ catkin_init_workspace
$ tar xvf ../../ros-indigo-gmapping_1.3.7.orig.tar.gz
$ mv ros-indigo-gmapping-1.3.7/ gmapping
$ gedit gmapping/src/slam_gmapping.cpp
```

Change line 409 from:

```
  if (fabs(fabs(scan.angle_min) - fabs(scan.angle_max)) > FLT_EPSILON)
```

to:

```
  if (fabs(fabs(scan.angle_min) - fabs(scan.angle_max)) > 0.003) // this is the value for Kinect
```

Save and close the file. Go back to commandline:

```
$ cd ..
$ catkin_make
$ sudo cp devel/lib/gmapping/slam_gmapping* /opt/ros/indigo/lib/gmapping/
```

This works for me.

---

Originally posted by [chuong](https://answers.ros.org/users/23203/chuong/) with karma: 41 on 2015-07-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-07-16**:
+1 only as a temporary workaround for the particular usecase (turtlebot_gazebo in this case). Since `gmapping` is a package that's fundamental enough, we need a permanent solution. I've opened a related [PR](https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping/pull/33).

**Comment by [Salocin808](https://answers.ros.org/users/23159/salocin808/) on 2015-07-16**:
why is this only working for turtlebot_gazebo?

**Comment by [Salocin808](https://answers.ros.org/users/23159/salocin808/) on 2015-07-16**:
This is not working for me. Followed the instructions but still getting same error. Any ideas?
(I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS and Turtlebot 2)

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-07-16**:
@Salocin808 Instant workaround (not a "solution") can be to play with `FLT_EPSILON` value that works for you. Once you find the smallest working value sharing it with us would be beneficial.

**Comment by [Salocin808](https://answers.ros.org/users/23159/salocin808/) on 2015-07-16**:
@130s Ok thanks for your help! I am already at home but will try it tomorrow morning.

**Comment by [Salocin808](https://answers.ros.org/users/23159/salocin808/) on 2015-07-17**:
@130s I changed the error message so that it prints out the difference between the angles:

```
[ERROR] [1437121911.683298899]: Edited: Scan message must contain angles from -x to x, i.e. angle_min (0.513185) = -angle_max (0.499907). min-max = 0.013278
```

Maybe EPSILON should be 0.03?

**Comment by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) on 2015-07-18**:
please guys, don't try to find workarounds: report the bug at least; better, help fixing it :)

**Comment by [Salocin808](https://answers.ros.org/users/23159/salocin808/) on 2015-07-21**:
well, after changing the value to 0.03 I never had problems.. where should I report the bug?